# fit regression of the form y = x ** a with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_ = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 8.0, 16.0, 33.0])
y_ = np.array([0.4, 0.55, 0.62, 0.72, 0.76, 0.8])
```

I want to fit a regression model of the form `y = x ** a` where `a` is estimated.
The purpose is to extrapolate to (much) larger, unseen values of `x`.
NB: I need to force my model to go through 
`(0, 0)`.

Not sure whether this is the best way to go, but so far I have tried to cast this as finding the constant that best fits `log(y) / log(x)`. I have:

```
x_ = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 8.0, 16.0, 33.0])
logx_ = np.log(x_)
y_ = np.array([0.4, 0.55, 0.62, 0.72, 0.76, 0.8])
logy_ = np.log(y_)
y = logy_ / logx_
x = x_
print "y: ", y
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 0)
print "param estimates: ", z

p = np.poly1d(z)
p30 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 30))

xp = np.linspace(0, 35, 6)
_ = plt.plot(x, np.exp(y*np.log(x)), '.', xp, np.exp(p(xp)*np.log(x)), '-')
plt.ylim(0,1.0)
plt.show()
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. 
Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong, and provide an answer?

Comment: It's much better to fit a linear to `ln(y)` vs `ln(x)`, since according to your model `ln(y)=a*ln(x)`. Then you need the slope. But I'm not sure you can force `polyfit` to skip a constant; you might have to use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` (but then you can fit the model directly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fits a pure `y = x ** a` by least squares on  `logy_ = a * logx_`:

```
a = np.linalg.lstsq(logx_[:, np.newaxis], logy_)[0][0]
```

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
log(y+1) = a * log(x+1)
```

This gets you your exponential and forces through `(0, 0)`

```
f = lambda x, a: (x + 1) ** a - 1
x = np.random.rand(200, 1) * 100
y = f(x, 1.5) + np.random.rand(*x.shape) * 200

plt.plot(x, y, '.')
```

[image]

```
log_x_plus_1 = np.log(x + 1)
log_y_plus_1 = np.log(y + 1)
a = np.linalg.pinv(log_x_plus_1.T.dot(log_x_plus_1)).dot(log_x_plus_1.T).dot(log_y_plus_1)[0][0]

plt.plot(x, y, '.')
plt.plot(x, f(x, a), 'r.')
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `log(y+1) = a * log(x+1)`?

Comment: Yes!  I do.  I'll update post when I have a chance.  The idea is there.

Comment: But in that case, you're not fitting `y = x ** a` but `y+1 = (x+1) ** a`...